# How to set DisableHWAcceleration key if HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\ does not exist?

Tags: wpf, registry, hardware-acceleration

I checked few articles in internet and they all seems to assume that one can navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\
```

with Registry Editor.

I don't have in my Win7 Enterprise machine Avalon.Graphics at all in Registry Editor. So how do I set DisableHWAcceleration = 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the registry key does not exist, then create it.  I don't believe the `Avalon.Graphics` key is expected to exist by default.  It hasn't existed any time I needed to set a WPF-related registry override, but they always got picked up after I added the key manually.

I don't know why so many articles are unclear on that point.

Comment: Thanks! Do  you mean that I should create Avalon.Graphics key and under it the  DWORD DisableHWAcceleration with value = 1?